# Using Express to serve static files, return Cannot GET?

Tags: node.js, express, static

I try to use Express to serve static files.

Here is my code: `test.js`

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.listen(8080);
```

Here is my folder directory:

```
├── public
│   ├── folder1
│   │     └── many .js files
│   └── folder2
│         └── many .xml files
├── test.js
│
└── node_modules
```

My node is `6.5.0`, npm is `3.10.3`

After I run `node test.js`, everything is OK. However, I open `http://localhost:8080/`, it returns `Cannot GET /`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you're receiving `Cannot GET /` is because you do not have a route for `GET /` just like the error says, if you want to see what is in your `/public` folder you would need to make a request to `http://localhost:8080/folder1`or `http://localhost:8080/folder2`.

To have express return something besides `Cannot GET /` when requesting `http://localhost:8080` then add the following to your `test.js`

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  return res.status(200).send('This is the root of my express application');
});
```

Comment: YES! I try to `http://localhost:8080/folder1/fileName.js`, and it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a index.html in the public folder.

Starter guide for express:
http://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html